# Is there a way to select an element that isn't child?

Tags: css

Is there a way to select an element that isn't child? I'm not't really sure how to word this or explain it. Hopefully the code will speak for itself:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBhgV/3/

HTML:

```
<div title="section-1">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="item-1">
            <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
<div title="section-2">
    <div>Test Drop</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[title=section-2] {
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ [title=section-2] {
    display: block;
}
```

Is there a way that when you check the box, it will show section-2 without making section-2 a child of section 1?

Comment: No; that would require traversing through the element's parents.

Answer (score 2):

change your code from

```
<div title="section-1">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="item-1">
            <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
<div title="section-2">
    <div>Test Drop</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="item-1"/>
   <div title="section-1">
    <div>
        <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div title="section-2">
    <div>Test Drop</div>
</div>
```

then your css should work fine. You can set the visiblity of your checkbox to hidden and position it absolutely somewhere off the page.

my site uses a similar technique for the navigation so you can see how it works by inspecting the code.

http://www.aktof.ca/

**changed your fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/kBhgV/4/

Comment: That's right, it is not what the OP wanted, but as fas as I know, it's the only way to have it working only in CSS

Comment: It's not really a child, its a sibling but okies :)